# Should we encrypt data stored in aspnet_Profile table

Tags: database, security, encryption

We are doing security updates on all our sites and two steps involved in it is encrypting data at transfer and encrypting data at rest.

Adding SSL certificate will encrypt data at transfer and we need to encrypt all the data in database which is classified as personal details of users.

Some of these details are stored in aspnet_profile table.

Can anyone please advice about encrypting data stored in this table?
Do we really need to encrypt the data to as part of the security update?

Answer (score 0):

It depends. Do you want to be able to access information of the user, or is the user the only person who has access to the data?

In the first occasion, I think that encryption of data is only meaningful if the database is stored in a separate server from the web server, or if the decryption keys are stored in a separate server. In order to decrypt the data and present it to the users you need to decrypt it. If the encrypted data and the keys are in the same server, and that server gets compromised, the attackers will be able to decrypt everything, as they will have access to the keys as well. If you store them separately, they will need to compromise 2 (or more) servers, which will probably be harder. Also, since encryption is a heavy task, you should probably only encrypt sensitive data (whatever you consider sensitive for your scenario). Data like passwords should not be encrypted, but hashed and salted instead (there is plenty of information online on how to do that). If you decide to encrypt everything you should also have different keys for each user, so that if one key gets compromised, only one user will be affected.

If you want only the user to see the stored information, you should know that will not have access to it (unless you store it in a separate database as well without encryption, or encrypted with your own keys). A user who loses their password will be in trouble if you don't have a backup of the information using your own key (or storing them in plaintext - which defies the purpose). Even if you have a copy of the data though, recovery of the data would mean decrypting it using your key (if not stored in plaintext), and encrypting it again with the new key set by the user. This can be a heavy task if the amount of data is big. Finally, if you want only the user to have access and full responsibility (so you will not be able to access it **at all**), you should make it clear, and preferably perform the encryption on the client side. Again, only the sensitive data would better be encrypted. Also, information like usernames and passwords for user login should not be encrypted. The same principle of salted hashing applies to the passwords in this occasion as well.

In both scenarios, you should keep in mind that losing the keys means potentially losing **all** the data! You should also use some good encryption scheme, like AES CFB mode.

Overall, whether it is a good idea or not really depends on the sensitivity of the data and the budget that you have. Regular backups will be required, as well as handling things with care so that no keys get lost. Additional servers will also probably be required, and if the amount of traffic that the websites get is large, probably you will need powerful servers in order to be able to deal with this heavy task.